# Adding parent xml node using xslt version 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am getting XML structure with missing parent node, so while passing this XML structure to XSLT i am getting error as "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed".

If i can add parent tag to the existing XML Structure, issue will be resolved. Can anyone help me here?

**Below is the XML structure i am receiving:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SARIETransferRq>
    <SARIETransferRqHeader>
        <CorporateID>Sample123</CorporateID>
        <CorpReferenceNumber>Sample123</CorpReferenceNumber>
    </SARIETransferRqHeader>
    <SARIETransferRqBody>
        <AccountNumber>0000111111111222222</AccountNumber>
        <DebitCurrency>SAR</DebitCurrency>
        <TransferAmount>12</TransferAmount>
        <TransferCurrency>SAR</TransferCurrency>
        <BeneficiaryName>SAMPLE NAME</BeneficiaryName>
        <BeneficiaryAccountNumber>Sample1231111111</BeneficiaryAccountNumber>
        <BeneficiaryAddress1>733r</BeneficiaryAddress1>
        <BeneficiaryAddress2>6Sample123y</BeneficiaryAddress2>
        <BeneficiaryAddress3>1Sample123ver</BeneficiaryAddress3>
        <BankBIC>AAAAAA</BankBIC>
        <PaymentDate>2021-02-24</PaymentDate>
        <Instructions1>qewerr</Instructions1>
        <Instructions2>luaba</Instructions2>
        <Instructions3>fadjiugu</Instructions3>
        <Instructions4>rifdij</Instructions4>
        <Description>sample description for service fee</Description>
        <AMLPurposeCode>BB</AMLPurposeCode>
    </SARIETransferRqBody>
</SARIETransferRq>
<Signature>
    <SignatureValue>sample</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
```

**Desired Output:**

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SampleRoot>
<SARIETransferRq>
    <SARIETransferRqHeader>
        <CorporateID>Sample123</CorporateID>
        <CorpReferenceNumber>Sample123</CorpReferenceNumber>
    </SARIETransferRqHeader>
    <SARIETransferRqBody>
        <AccountNumber>0000111111111222222</AccountNumber>
        <DebitCurrency>SAR</DebitCurrency>
        <TransferAmount>12</TransferAmount>
        <TransferCurrency>SAR</TransferCurrency>
        <BeneficiaryName>SAMPLE NAME</BeneficiaryName>
        <BeneficiaryAccountNumber>Sample1231111111</BeneficiaryAccountNumber>
        <BeneficiaryAddress1>733r</BeneficiaryAddress1>
        <BeneficiaryAddress2>6Sample123y</BeneficiaryAddress2>
        <BeneficiaryAddress3>1Sample123ver</BeneficiaryAddress3>
        <BankBIC>AAAAAA</BankBIC>
        <PaymentDate>2021-02-24</PaymentDate>
        <Instructions1>qewerr</Instructions1>
        <Instructions2>luaba</Instructions2>
        <Instructions3>fadjiugu</Instructions3>
        <Instructions4>rifdij</Instructions4>
        <Description>sample description for service fee</Description>
        <AMLPurposeCode>BB</AMLPurposeCode>
    </SARIETransferRqBody>
</SARIETransferRq>
<Signature>
    <SignatureValue>sample</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
</SampleRoot>

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: What technology are you using to process this message? You will probably have to turn it into valid XML before passing it to the XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is not a well-formed XML document, so it can't be processed "as-is" by XSLT. However, it is a well-formed XML entity, so it can be incorporated by reference into a well-formed XML document (provided the XML parser resolves external entities, which not all do these days, because of questionable security concerns).

Create a file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE SampleRoot [
<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "my.xml">
]>
<SampleRoot >&e;</SampleRoot>
```

where my.xml is your XML fragment, and pass this wrapper document as the input to the XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse this in XSLT 1.0, I'm afraid. It needs to be well-formed XML.

You will need to use some other tool to strip off the first line, containing the XML declaration (which is optional, and doesn't say anything useful), and then enclose the result in `SampleRoot` tags.